# How do I use use-package with diminish in my init.el?

Tags: use-package

It looks like use-package recently made a change and `diminish` is its own package. How do I install `diminish` which is its own package now?

Here is what the top of my `init.el` looks like:

```
;; Save customizations in a separate file (custom.el)
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom.el")
(load custom-file 'noerror) ; Prevent errors if custom.el does not exist

;; Package setup
;; (require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             t)
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'diminish)
(require 'bind-key)

(package-initialize)
```

This fails with `Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, diminish`

I can add `(use-package diminish ...` to fix the issue but I'd like to know if there is an idiomatic way to set up `use-package`

Comment: FYI `diminish.el` was *always* its own library/package. You don't need `use-package` in order to use it.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug. It is fixed in recent versions of `use-package` (as of 2017-12-12, at least). Available on [MELPA](https://melpa.org/).